# SmtpClient.SendAsync - Stop application after the call

Tags: c#, winforms, smtpclient

I am building winforms application that has to send emails. I want to be able to call SmtpClient.SendAsync method and after that allow to user to close the app immediately (I am not interested to get sending results in callback function). If user stops application, the emails are not sended....If application stay running, the emails are sended as expected...
Any suggestions, how can i pass all relevant details to smtp server and close my app?

Thanks

Comment: That is not how it works, that is not how any of this works... Async does not mean _"I'm not interested in the results"_ nor _"keep doing this even though I terminate my application"_ and sending an email consists of talking to an SMTP server and keeping open the connection until the entire message is sent - for each message. This takes time, and increasingly so the more messages you want to send. If you want to and are able to enqueue messages, you may want to consider offloading the actual sending to a Windows Service.

Comment: or (in addition to what CodeCaster said) spawn execution to a separate process.

Comment: I I have understand you right, you suggest to replace the sending logic to Windows Service, and to call it from my winforms app?

Comment: @Lev yes, that's what I'm suggesting. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operation needs to be allowed to execute until the delivery to the SMTP server is complete. If you really don't care about results, you could spawn a foreground thread to execute the delivery. This way, if the user closes the application, its GUI would be unloaded, but the foreground thread would persist until the operation completes. Once all foreground threads belonging to the process have terminated, the process itself would also terminate.

```
var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => smtpClient.Send(message)));
t.IsBackground = false;
t.Start();
```

**Edit**: As CodeCaster has pointed out, this approach assumes that your application's process will keep running after the user closes its windows. The operation will fail if the user shuts down the system (or manually kills the process) before the thread has completed.

Comment: And then the user shuts down their computer, or OP gets complaints their application keeps running after closing it. Not saying this isn't a solution, just pointing out some drawbacks.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Valid points. I assumed this was a "best-effort" attempt anyway since the user doesn't care about results.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer match 100% my needs.